# When moving to a new domain should I ensure the old domain returns 410?

Tags: seo, google, multiple-domains

I recently moved from a .com domain to a .co.uk, this was a few months ago now, and essentially I still have my .com pointing to the same server as the .co.uk, and if accessed it performs a redirect to my .co.uk.

Is it better to have the .com now returning a 410 and empty response? I should I retain the redirect setup I have in place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retain the redirect, at least for as long as there are external links pointing to the old domain. It should, of course, be a permanent (301) redirect.

You could also set up Google Webmaster Tools on both domains and, on the old one, set the Change of Address tool accordingly. This doesn't do anything the redirect won't, but it may help to ensure Google updates its index more quickly.